# Error while installing Rust on Windows x64

Tags: rust

When I install Rust (even with admin permission) I get this error:

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hopefully their installer can cope with spaces in paths, but nonetheless, have you tried installing to a path that doesn't have spaces in it (e.g. `C:\Rust`)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried and I get the same problem.

Comment: Error 2 is file not found, use procmon to find out which file

Comment: I thought it was a problem easier to fix.

Comment: You have enough free space on your disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anti-virus software may have deleted or quarantined the file.

On my system, avast! detected malware in rustc.exe a few weeks ago (which I reported, haven't checked back to see if the false positive was addressed).

Comment: I'll see if I can disable avast